# iOS dismisskeyboard on tap outside of the searchbar

Tags: ios, keyboard, uisearchbar, dismiss

I have a tabbed bar application and in one of the tab I have a searchbar.

As expected when user focuses the searchbar, the keyboard appears, but over the tabbar. Therefore I would like to dismiss it when the user tap outside the searchbar.

I use the following code :

In `viewDidLoad`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tapRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

and the `handleTap`

```
- (void) handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

the problem is that the keyboard is dismissed even when I tap the search options which is not the behavior I want. I want the keyboard to dismiss only when the tap is outside the search bar.

[image]

I also tried using `recognizer.view` in `handleTap` to identified when the tap was performed, but in there is a single view and that case and no possibility to identify the tap location.

So the question is : how can I dismiss the keyboard when the user taps ouside the searchbar and not dismiss the keyboard when a user tap a search option button.

Comment: you have used the sear bar in tableview, ur coding is fine , it working in segment also is not working in tableview correct

Comment: Change class identity of View object in Interface Builder(as I understand in Xcode 4 its Control) from UIView to UIControl and Connect TouchDown method in events list with File's Owner and check method backgroundTap. - (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

Comment: checking `if([recognizer.view isEqual:self.tableView]){    }` in `handleTap:` not working for you?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I already tried and as I mentioned in the question it appears that only 1 view is present therefore a tap on the options button or on the background give the same result.

Comment: did you add search bar and tab bar on `UITableView`?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma TabController -> Navigation Controller -> TableView and searchbar is in the tableview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [self.view.superview.superview endEditing:YES]; //or [self.view.superview endEditing:YES];
  [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

other choice

add the `Cancel Button` to `UI search bar`

```
 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

[image]

Comment: +1 the idea of using the cancel button is a good idea. Now for the touch event, for now I don't manage to trigger it. Whenever I tap it's not called.

Comment: I forget to add that user interaction is enabled. I don't understand why touchesBegan is not called.

Comment: touch began is working well in normal view, but u r called in superview (tableview) that s y is not working well